# Why can't access the image tint color from inside the scrollViewDidScroll

Tags: swift, xcode, null, uiscrollview

I have the following code:

```
class SegmentedControlViewController: UIViewController, UIScrollViewDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var happyOutlet: UIButton!
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        scrollView?.delegate = self
    
    }
    
   func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
       
       if scrollView.contentOffset.x > 490 {
              
        happyOutlet?.imageView?.tintColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0.3411764801, green: 0.6235294342, blue: 0.1686274558, alpha: 1)
       }
       else {
           print("nope")
       }
   }

    
    @IBAction func happy(_ sender: UIButton) {

        happyOutlet.imageView?.tintColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0.9294117647, green: 0.4705882353, blue: 0.07450980392, alpha: 1)

    }
}
```

When I click the button the image tint color changes, although when I scroll more than 450 the tint color doesn't change. I know that my code is right because inside the `if` statement I tried printing something and it worked so it's something with the button outlet I guess. Also unless I unwrap the happyOutlet in the if statement I get the unwrap optional is nil error.

**EDIT**

I changed my func to this:

```
   func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
       
           if scrollView.contentOffset.x > 20 {
           print("greater than 20")
           happyOutlet?.imageView?.tintColor = .red
       }
       else {
           print("less than 21")
           happyOutlet?.imageView?.tintColor = .green
       }
   }
```

Although still same thing just the color isn't changing at all, although the stuff gets printed to the console. Also if I don't add the question marks I get the error. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Share a [minimal-reproducible-example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: @Frankenstein this is one minus the storyboard

Comment: @coder123 - what are you doing here? This looks similar to your last question... Are you trying to call `scrollViewDidScroll()` yourself again?  I just gave this a try, and it works fine for me -- ***without the happyOutlet? "unwrapping"***. If you're getting `unwrap optional nil` then you've done something wrong.

Comment: @DonMag any ideas what I could have done wrong, I tried connecting the outlet again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit 2**

Take a look at: https://github.com/DonMag/DidScrollTest

Simple example, plus your project with ***lots*** of edits.

---

**Edit**

After getting more detail and looking at your sample project...

You have an instance of `SegmentedControlViewController` which uses a `UIContainerView` to load your "scroll view" controller. However, your have also assign `SegmentedControlViewController` as the class for *that* controller.

The two controllers in your Storyboard have different elements connected via `@IBOutlet`. This will not work (as you have seen).

To accomplish your design, you need a different class for your "scroll view" controller, and you'll want to use a custom delegate / protocol pattern to communicate between them.

As a side note: It would serve you well to learn some of the fundamentals.

In a number of places in your code, you use:

```
happyView?.alpha = 1
```

However, that `?` means:

**If the variable preceding it is Nil, DON'T do what comes after it.**

So, you're avoiding `nil` errors by telling the code not to execute, but that doesn't help when you *want* it to execute.

When you write this:

```
happyView.alpha = 1
```

and your app crashes with `Unexpectedly found nil...`, you need to ***fix*** that - not edit your code to ignore it.

---

Assuming:

- you have a scroll view connected to `@IBOutlet var scrollView: UIScrollView!`
- you have a button, connected to `@IBOutlet var happyOutlet: UIButton!`
- you have an image set for the button

This will change the tint color of the button's image view between red and green, as you scroll 20-pts left and back right. As you scroll, it will also `print()` the scroll view's content offset x and a message whether it is greater than or less than 20:

```
class SegmentedControlViewController: UIViewController {
    
    @IBOutlet var scrollView: UIScrollView!
    @IBOutlet var happyOutlet: UIButton!
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        // assign the delegate
        scrollView.delegate = self
        
    }
    
}

extension SegmentedControlViewController: UIScrollViewDelegate {
    func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {

        print("content offset x:", scrollView.contentOffset.x)
        
        // if we've scrolled left more than 20 points
        if scrollView.contentOffset.x > 20 {
            print("greater than 20")
            happyOutlet.imageView?.tintColor = .red
        }
        else {
            print("less than 21")
            happyOutlet.imageView?.tintColor = .green
        }

    }
}
```

**Note:**

If the `happyOutlet` button ***is a subview of the scroll view***, in case it's not obvious, the button must be more than 20-pts from the leading edge of the scroll view... otherwise you won't see it change when it is scrolled out of view.

Comment: @coder123 - a tip: Think about what you're asking when you post here. The code in your question ***does not even show*** a declaration for `scrollView`. What else are you not including (that is very likely part of the problem)?

Comment: I forgot to include that although other than that my code is pretty much the same so I'm just wondering if you have any ideas what I should try next.

Comment: @coder123 - *"pretty much the same"* **!=** *"the same"*. You need to describe what you're doing to get to this view controller, and show the ***actual code**. Very difficult to help when you post code that you are not using.

Comment: @coder123 - here is a complete example: https://github.com/DonMag/DidScrollTest ... compare it to your code and see what's different.

Comment: I copied some of my project and the put it in a new project although now the issue that was happening to me before with no outlet changes being made within the scrollDidScroll function is also happening in the viewDidLoad function. No changes are being applied to the outlets within any functions. Here is the Github link. Feel free to play around with it and try and figure out the problem because I am out of ideas.

   https://github.com/coder123-star/testScrollView

Comment: @coder123 - this is why I emphasize posting ***details***. In your Storyboard, you have **two** view controllers with the custom class `SegmentedControlViewController`. One has only a scroll view connected to `@IBOutlet  weak var scrollView: UIScrollView!`. When the view controller loads, your code is trying to access `@IBOutlet`s that are ***NOT IN THE CONTROLLER***.

Comment: @coder123 - see the **Edit** at the top of my answer.

Comment: @coder123 - I made a bunch of changes to your GitHub project and added it to my example (https://github.com/DonMag/DidScrollTest). Run it, then study the code (plenty of comments provided).

Comment: Thank you thank you your a life saverrrrrrrrr. Turns out it was because I had it in a container view, thank you so much